# For As400 not able to exit using F3 key.Is any alternative key can be used for exit functinality?

Tags: ibm-midrange

**strong text**Not able to exit from As400 using f3 in dell inspiron 15 3000 laptop

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming, but about how to use an unnamed terminal emulation.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to Dell's defaulting the function key configuration to "Multimedia".

Try pressing the "Fn" key and "F3" together, this should send F3 to your 5250 emulator.

The setting "Function Key Behaviour" in your BIOS changes the behaviour of the function keys. Changing said setting to "Function Key" will mean the Function Keys are primary and the multimedia options are secondary instead (the latter will then need to be accessed with the Fn key).